# Чтение файла в jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Проблема в следующем, есть файл `test.json`

```
{"ts":1659835624,"updates":[[61,200378273,1],[4,70,17,200378273,1593455637," ... ","test"]]}
```

Как можно прочитать только одну из частей `updates`?
Пытался как-то так сделать, но читает все сразу.

```
#include "json/json.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
Json::Value aaaa;
std::ifstream file("c:/test.json", std::ifstream::binary);
file >> aaaa;

std::cout << aaaa["updates"];
}
```

Comment: https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html

Comment: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: `aaaa["updates"][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <json/json.h>

int main() {
    std::istringstream stream { R"({ "updates" : [[1,2], [3,4]] })" };
    Json::Value json;
    stream >> json;

    for (const auto& u : json["updates"])
    {
        std::cout << u << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

У класса `Json::Value` перегружен subscript оператор ([...]), что позволяет:

1. Получить доступ к объекту по ключу 
   Пример: `json["updates"] -> [[1,2], [3,4]]`
2. Получить доступ к элементу массива по индексу 
   Пример: `json["updates"][0] -> [1,2]`

Так же Вы можете использовать [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (используется в примере):

```
for (const auto& u : json["updates"])
{
    std::cout << u << std::endl;
}
```

Или "традиционный" index loop:

```
for (auto i = 0U; i < json["updates"].size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << json["updates"][i] << std::endl;
}
```

Чтобы проверить, являет ли Json-value массивом, вызовите метод `isArray()`.